# I can like my facebook page but my friend can't?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have make a facebook page I have put like button on my page.

it's work until I move it from "fb" directory to root directory.

now someone can check this linked

http://kris.byethost10.com/

in this page when you like it's not worked show me error that

```
Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: We're working on this issue and will have it fixed soon. Check the Known Issues on Facebook page for more information.
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me... Are you still experiencing problems with this?

Comment: @Lix same sorry message again,

Answer (score 0):

May be the issue with browser of your friend, try checking with your account on your friend's browser also check [this link](http://forums.kanoapps.com/showthread.php?8210-FB-Error-Message-Error-processing-request-Sorry-this-Feature-isn-t-available-...) may be it'll be helpful to you